# DropDown Value return save all instead of anyone

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, drop-downs

I am getting my shipping value from Magento,

sp_cost.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('./../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true); 
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

function getShippingEstimate($productId,$productQty,$countryId,$postcode ) {

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('english')->getId());
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
    $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);

    $quote->addProduct($_product, $productQty);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($countryId)->setPostcode($postcode); 
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

    $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

    $shippingRates = array();
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate):
            if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
                $shippingRates[] =  array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice());
            }
    endforeach;

    return $shippingRates;

}

###### Post #######
if(isset($_POST['zip_postal_code']) && isset($_POST['country']))
    {
     $zip_postal_code = $_POST['zip_postal_code'];
     $country = $_POST['country'];

}

$results = getShippingEstimate('14419','1',$country,$zip_postal_code);
###### Post #######
// $results = getShippingEstimate('14419','1',"IND","642001"); // Predefined Value

$count = -1;
echo "<select name='shipping_cost'>";
foreach ($results as $result): 
$count++;
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $count; ?>"> <?php echo $result["Title"]." - Rs ".$result["Price"];?>
 </option>
 <?php
endforeach;
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

and i am using ajax for customer choose anyone, if customer selects anyone of dropdown all the values save into table, how to restrict?

Form

```
<tr>
    <th>Shipping Cost (Rs) : </th> 
    <td id="findata"></td>
     <input type="hidden" name="shipping_cost"  id="shipping_cost"/>
</tr>
```

Ajax :

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#new').on('change',function(){

        var zip = $("#zip_postal_code").val();
        var country = $("#country").val();


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // url: "ajax_ship_cost_data.php",
        url: "sp_cost.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: { zip_postal_code: zip, country: country},
        success: function(data)
        {
            // Check the output of ajax call on firebug console
             //console.log(data);
            $('#findata').html(data);
            $('#shipping_cost').val(data);

        }
});

});
});
</script>
```

FYI -> https://snag.gy/fvTWXB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As you want your customer to choose from one of available shipping methods. then use this code. The only change I have made is the value of your dropdown, you have used `$count`, instead of `$count` you need to use price in dropdown value

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('./../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
ini_set('display_errors',true);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');

function getShippingEstimate($productId,$productQty,$countryId,$postcode ) {

    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('english')->getId());
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
    $_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);

    $quote->addProduct($_product, $productQty);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId($countryId)->setPostcode($postcode);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

    $_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();

    $shippingRates = "";
    foreach ($_rates as $_rate):
        if($_rate->getPrice() > 0) {
            $shippingRates[] =  array("Title" => $_rate->getMethodTitle(), "Price" => $_rate->getPrice());
        }
    endforeach;

    return $shippingRates;

}

###### Post #######
if(isset($_POST['zip_postal_code']) && isset($_POST['country']))
{
    $zip_postal_code = $_POST['zip_postal_code'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];

}

$results = getShippingEstimate('14419','1',$country,$zip_postal_code);
###### Post #######
// $results = getShippingEstimate('14419','1',"IND","642001"); // Predefined Value

echo "<select name='shipping_cost'>";
foreach ($results as $result):
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $result["Price"]; ?>"> <?php echo $result["Title"]." - Rs ".$result["Price"];?>
    </option>
    <?php
endforeach;
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: output -> https://snag.gy/EYQsNt.jpg   code -> https://paste.ofcode.org/dPh3ActVWfuhtawg2V3svx

Comment: The value not applying on form

Comment: Any help.......?

Comment: Updated my answer, check code now

Comment: Yes now working, display minimum rate, is possible to let a customer choose the courier service?

Comment: If you want your customer to choose courier service, then your previous code is fine. Your previous code showing all available shipping methods.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the customer choose anyone both the value saves into the table, could you pls help me with this?

Comment: Let me try, save code in the answer as backup, I will update it

Comment: FYI -> https://snag.gy/d8wMAm.jpg

Comment: Check answer now. I have updated it

Comment: No luck -> https://snag.gy/7OWSnt.jpg

Comment: code : https://paste.ofcode.org/VLd2wcVF7iNmikUQewm5RR

Comment: This is the best I could offer, I think you need to go with the previous one that I have shared

Comment: Really thanks for your time bro, let me try..

Comment: Welcome, hope you find solution on this

Comment: Finally did,  In Form :: <tr>
  <th>Shipping Cost (Rs) : </th> 
  
  <td>
  <select id="findata" name="shipping_cost">
  
  </select></td>
  
   <!-- 
   <td id="findata"></td>
   <input type="hidden" name="shipping_cost"  id="shipping_cost"/> -->
 </tr>

Comment: Great. I am glade that you solve it :)